# How do I process this simple JSON string using DataContractJsonSerializer in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

JSON string returned from API:

```
{"status":0,"data":{"respondents":[{"date_modified":"2015-05-18 19:08:07","respondent_id":"3973604066"},{"date_modified":"2015-05-11 20:00:30","respondent_id":"3958700049"}],"page":1,"page_size":1000}}
```

If this was XML I would just use LINQ and store it as a List inside a List.

I am certain that if I can get an answer of how to process this I can apply it to a much higher level.

I am using .net 3.5 or 4.0.

I cannot install Json.Net without going through the CCB.

Thanks.

This is my code:

class Program
    {

```
    public class StatusObj
    {
        public int status {get; set; }
        public List<DataObj> data {get; set;}
    }

    public class DataObj 
    {
        public List<RespondentObj> respondents { get; set; }
        public int page {get; set;}
        public int page_size {get; set;}
    }

    public class RespondentObj
    {
        public DateTime date_modified {get; set;}
        public int respondent_id {get; set;}
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Pulling WSDL");

        // Removed the API Pull since I don't have issue there

        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string json_returned = reader.ReadToEnd();
                               // "{\"status\":0,\"data\":{\"respondents\":[{\"date_modified\":\"2015-05-18 19:08:07\",\"respondent_id\":\"3973604066\"},{\"date_modified\":\"2015-05-11 20:00:30\",\"respondent_id\":\"3958700049\"}],\"page\":1,\"page_size\":1000}}";
        Console.WriteLine(json_returned);

        //This is what Cody Suggested
        var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var results = deserializer.Deserialize<StatusObj>(json_returned);

        foreach (var x in results.data)
        {
            foreach (var y in x.respondents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.page);
                Console.WriteLine(y.respondent_id);
                Console.WriteLine(y.date_modified);
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

Comment: What is CCB ?  your question is not clear.

Comment: @Kashif Change Control Board, in short, they would need approval.

Comment: basically you can not install any json library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the built in JavaScriptSerializer with matching classes. So you would have something like this:

```
public class StatusObj{
    public int status {get; set; }
    public DataObj data { get; set; }
}

public class DataObj {
    public List<RespondentObj> respondents {get set;}
    public int page {get; set;}
    public int page_size {get; set;}
}

public class RespondentObj{
    public DateTime date_modified {get; set;}
    public Int64 respondent_id {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can deserialize your stream like this:

```
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var results = deserializer.Deserialize<StatusObj>(stream);
```

Comment: I am still **not** getting this to populate into results. I assume I am following your code that this should manfest into A StatusList with A dataList in it with a Respondent List in that. And that I can use nested foreach to get to the data. But results is just not populating. I appreciate your help and it seems so straightforward.

Comment: @KeithL is it throwing an error or just returning empty results? Assuming the names are identical and the structure is the same you might also just try using arrays instead of lists if those are not populating

Comment: I added my code above minus the API pull part. I can't seem to get values into results.

Comment: @KeithL ok I think I figured it out, I was reading the JSON string incorrectly, the 'data' property isn't a List, it's simply an object containing a list, I'm editing the code now

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I can really run with this now and the mistake that we made has taught me a valuable lesson as well.